# render function is not rendering items

Tags: reactjs, rendering, jsx

I'm trying to render across an array object in react.js using this:

```
const myservice = getAllServices(uid).then(service => {
      renderallServices(service);
      return service;
  });
```

where renderallServices(service) is

```
const renderallServices = (services) => (
  <>
  {services.map(service => (
          <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
          <ServiceCard service={service}>
          </ServiceCard>
          {console.log(service)}
          </Row>
        ))

    }
  </>

  );
```

Note: the reason my renderallServices function is being called inside of .then() is because without that it returns a promise instead of the actual array object I want. 
I know renderallServices is being called because the {console.log(service)} is returning each element in the array like I would expect. However, none of the JSX is being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

What contains `service` ? Is it some `jsx` ? Because you are calling `renderAllServices()` which return jsx, but are returning `service` in your `.then`.

Comment: ah good catch. service is an array, and I deleted the return service part and replaced with return renderAllServices(service). still doesnt render tho

Comment: Can show us how you do use your `myservice ` variable please ? Because there is no sign of state update here, so coupled with async call, i think your component cna be rendered before the call is done, and since you don't trigger any re-rendering, it does not display anything

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a state variable to maintain the services and iterate through that state array variable inside the `return` of your component

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const App = ()=>{
 const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
 const myservice = getAllServices(uid).then(service => {
  setServices(service);
  return service;
 });
    return (
    <Fragment>
    {services.length>0&& 
      (<Fragment>
          services.map(service => (
           <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
             <ServiceCard service={service}>
             </ServiceCard>
             console.log(service)
            </Row>
           ))
       </Fragment>) 
    }
  </Fragment> 
    );
 }
```

Hopefully this Helps :)